# htaccess rewrite to remove url from path

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite

Due to a previously misconfigured rewrite rule I have a whole lot of errors listed in webmaster tools like the following:-

```
http://www.domain.com/www.domain.com/page.html
http://www.domain.com/www.domain.com/page-two.html
http://www.domain.com/www.domain.com/another-page.html
```

This looked promising https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976814/removing-string-from-url-using-htaccess but could not get it to work with the following:-

```
RewriteRule ^/www.domain.com/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/www\.domain\.com/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put `.` (full stops) in square brackets like that `[.]` then it should work.

EDIT:

This should work: `RewriteRule ^/www[.]domain[.]com/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]`

Full stops are now not treated as special characters.

Comment: Great, got it working with:

    RewriteRule ^www[.]domain[.]com/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

(no leading slash)